# Convert input number with commas into a number to perform calculations and then return the output with commas?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a function. The JavaScript function starts formating the input text field as soon as a user starts typing in a number. This is good so far. But, when I try to take that value to perform a simple calculation, I get Nan error. I am assuming, it is due to the commas. So, can I remove these commas from the input while parsing it into the computation? And, once, the value is calculated. I want to show it in the commas format as an output (Annual Salary).

```js
  $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
  }); 

  function calculateSalary() {
    var salary = document.getElementById("salary").value;
    var years = document.getElementById("years").value;

    var annumSalary = salary * years;
    document.getElementById("annumSalary").value = Math.round(annumSalary);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Salary</label>
<input class="form-control number" name="salary" id="salary"  required/>
<br>
<label>Years</label>
<input class="form-control" name="years" id="years" value="" type="number" required/>
<br>
<label>Annual Salary</label>
<input class="form-control number" name="annumSalary" id="annumSalary" value="" type="number" readonly/>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateSalary()" />
```

Comment: i updated the code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the commas from the string and convert from string to number:

```
const str = '123,456.78';
const num = parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

To convert back to string with commas:

```
const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(num);
```

Comment: const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(num); I had to change the const into var to make it to work. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work. Since you're calculating salaries, you might have a use case for something like `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format('123,456.78'));` You can find more examples on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

Dude, **just add `parseInt()`** when you get the value with the `document.getElementById('salary').value`
**And if you think the user will enter decimals, use parseFloat.**

Usually parseInt() and parseFloat() **will convert the string to numbers** escaping (common) things like (,.etc)

PS:
Also if you're using jQuery, use $('#salary').value to make it look simple.

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
  }); 

  function calculateSalary() {
    var salary = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
    var years = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value);

    var annumSalary = salary * years;
    document.getElementById("annumSalary").value = Math.round(annumSalary);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Salary</label>
<input class="form-control number" name="salary" id="salary"  required/>
<br>
<label>Years</label>
<input class="form-control" name="years" id="years" value="" type="number" required/>
<br>
<label>Annual Salary</label>
<input class="form-control number" name="annumSalary" id="annumSalary" value="" type="number" readonly/>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateSalary()" />
```

Comment: I followed what you said; but, now it is ignoring the digits after the comma while calculating the annual salary.

Comment: If you just call parseFloat on a string with commas, it's going to strip everything off after the first comma. `parseFloat('123,456,789') // 123`